# Payment methods on mobile applications

Tags: mobile, payment

I am thinking to write an application that will allow users to make payments to third parties.

I do not want to receive the money and then transfer it because it would cost money and time.

All the different payment methods that I found do not seem to allow this type of transactions.

Any suggestion?